# How to subtract data frame columns

Tags: r

How can I subtract a column(c-1) from last column(c) in data frame `u`

```
u<-data.frame(a1=c(10,10,10),a2=c(0,10,5),a3=c(10,20,30),a4=c(2,7,9))
```

Resulting data frame after subtraction.

```
  a1    a2  a3  a4
  10    -10 10  15
  10    0   10  -13
  10    -5  25  -21
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your [initial question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305894/how-to-calculate-running-row-sums) instead of posting a new one

Comment: @ A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 at any step of rowsum if the sum exceeds 30.

Comment: Judging by your example, you rather mean that you substract column `c-1` from column `c`, right?

Comment: Also I suppose the first element of `a4` should be `-8` (and not `15`) in the result?

Comment: And as A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 said, the second part of your question is still unclear.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 please ignore the 2nd part. I have removed it.

Comment: @Scarabee you are right, i just corrected it

Comment: @crumbly: what about my other comment? (`15` instead of `-8`)

Comment: To answer your question: provided you don't have hundreds of columns, you can do: `for (i in ncol(u):2) {u[, i] <- u[, i] - u[, i-1]}`.

Comment: @Scarabee i have around 300 columns

Comment: `U <- cbind(u[1], u[-1] - u[-ncol(u)]); replace(U, U < 0, 0); U`? Gets you to the part before your `rowSums` step.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
newData = matrix(t(unlist(lapply(2:ncol(u), function(x, u){-u[, x-1] + u[, x]}, u) )), ncol = ncol(u) - 1)

  result = data.frame(cbind(u$a1, newData))

  names(result) = paste0("a", 1:4)

  result
```